# Multiple shipments in one order Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, invoice, backorder, packing-slip

When a customer creates an order in Magento with lets say the following products:

Product A - 5 x
Product B - 5 x

Product A I have in stock and I want to ship this now. How can I create a different packing slip, and invoice for it. And later, create a packing slip, and invoice for Product B.

Im using Magento 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento you can create multiple shipments and invoices for one order. Just select the items qty you'd like to, say, ship and process as shown at the screen shot:

[image: shipment]

Comment: Hi Amasty, Thanks for your comment, thats really helpfull. Is there also a possibility to make two invoices?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same way.  Press the "invoice" button at the order view page and select the products at the next page. Pls vote or accept the answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: Hi Amasty, 
I cant edit the qty in the invoice page. 

It is saying: 
Qty: Ordered 6, shipped 5. 
Qty to invoice 6 ( without an input field)

Comment: I see what's going on, Ive set can capture true in a file. Thats why I couldnt edit the qty. Thanks anyway.